# How do JS/Ajax forms work with HotWire in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

Instead of rails_ujs I see a new method for running javascript. But on the first look it propably doesn't have the same functions.

Is **returning escaped html/partial for response** available with Stimulus/Turbo (Hotwire)?
What do dynamic/ajax/remote forms look like?

*This question propably also applies to older versions of Rails. In Rails 7 this is the prefered and default method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes hot-wire will take care of all of this.

1. Instead of format.js responses in the controller there is format.turbo_stream responses
2. they can be written inside of the controller or in a separate file with the same name as the method name just like ujs responses so for an update action it would be update.turbo_stream.erb

Take a look at the hotwire documentation they explain it very well.
https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams#streaming-from-http-responses

Comment: Thank you, I will try. Is there any general rule, in case when I should use turbo, and when I should use Stimulus? On the first look this 2 solutions can realize in most cases the same goal.

Comment: Yes Turbo should be used for 80% of the things you need done like updating content on the page replacing forms adding new content when user interacts anything that you need to do in javascript you can now do with ruby by returning turbo_streams. StimulusJs would be used for the remaining 20% of things that would take too long to go between web requests like a character count for example as Im typing this stack overflow is telling me how many characters I have left that would make more sense to do with stimulus then to make a request every-time I type.